# Getting and assigning the $BRANCH_NAME to an environment variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I want to get the `$BRANCH_NAME` and assign it to a variable in the `environment{}` so that I can manipulate it. I basically want to be able to do something like this:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    branch_name = (sh 'echo $BRANCH_NAME').toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

I couldn't really find a good way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: that feels pretty weird.. have you tried to access `env.BRANCH_NAME` in Groovy?

Comment: If you're using a multibranch job, then `env.BRANCH_NAME` is the correct way to go

Answer (score 0):

There's a environment variable expose by Jenkins itself.

```
   script {
          env.GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL = GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL
    }
```